# $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\log(|\sin(x)|)}{\log(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\log(|\sin(x)|)}{\log(x)}$ exist considering $\sin(x) = 0$ When $x=n\pi$?

Comment: It does not exist

Comment: You seem to have a good idea already. Keep going!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit inf is $-\infty$ and obtained when $\sin=0$, while the limit sup is $0$ and is obtained when $\sin=1$. The limit does not exist because the two limits are not equal.

Comment: Isn’t $\liminf$ $-1$?

Comment: It seems to me since $\sin(n\pi)=0$ so the log at these points is $-\infty$, the limit inf is $\infty$.